# Jest how-to mock component within the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

Say I have something like this

`index.js`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from './Button';

export class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.state.item}</div>;
  }
}

export class Modal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="modal">
        <Item url="www.stackoverflow.com/" />
        <Button>Great</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


// Redux stuff
// export default connect(...)
```

and I then wish to just test the `Modal` and mock the `Item`

I have tried something like

```js
// index.test.js
const Modal = jest.mock("Modal", () => {
  const ModalToTest = require.requireActual("./index.js")
  return ({
    Modal: ModalToTest,
    Item: jest.fn(() => null)
  })
})
```

But it don't work..

---

*Bonus info: I'm using named export in order to **test the component without redux***

Comment: How jest.mock performs is; first you need to import your real module with alias or relative path. Then you need to use jest.mock(<as same path your import>, implementation);

Comment: So if `index.test.js` then `const Modal = jest.mock("./", () => {...` it should work? or do I have to do `import { Modal, Item as ItemMock } from `./` and then do `jest.mock('./', () => <div /> )` - how do I specify it to `ItemMock`?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to give a try but, `import { Modal, Item as ItemMock }` completely imports your index.js and gives you Modal and Item as seperate modules. So what you have to do is, `jest.mock('./', () => {
    return {
        ItemMock: jest.fn(),
        Modal: jest.fn(),
    }
})`

Comment: @Tugayİlik tried your suggest (and a lot of other things) - but no luck so far...